# I need limit for particular characters in Python itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x

How I can find a way to get all combination with some limits for particular characters. For now I have only limit for all characters. But I want to have character "Q" 4 times in every combinations? Is that possible with my code?

I use itertools combination_with_replacement

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import collections




def combine(arr, s):
    return [x for x in combinations_with_replacement(symbols, s) if max(collections.Counter(x).values()) <= 3]

symbols = "LNhkPepm3684th"
max_length = 10 
set = 10



print(combine(symbols, set))
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. The code you've posted generates combinations of 10 of the characters in the string, and discards any that have over 3 of the same character. Are you trying to add another rule to filter by, modify the rule to do what you want, or something else?

Comment: Yes, correct. I have problem with that because they first generate combination and than discard it. Is there a way to generate it as it should. I tried to add one more rule to filter but if you have some idea how to do this without generate and discard please tell me. I need a code where I can get all combination from symbols I have with some limit. A=4 times Q=3 times and the rest of characters not to show more than 3. The rest of characters can show 1 time, 2 times but not more than 3. That's I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I notice that your `symbols` collection contains the letter "h" twice. I'm not sure whether your "must appear 0 or 1 or 2 times, but no more" restriction applies individually to each h, or whether it applies to all "h"es collectively. In other words, is "LLLLLNNNNhh3684hh" a legal result? The "first h" appears twice, and the "second h" appears twice, and so there are four instances of "h" total.

Here's an approach that works if all symbols are individually restricted and `"LLLLLNNNNhh3684hh"` is a legal result. it works on the principle that any combination of a sequence can be uniquely represented as a list of numbers indicating how many times the element at that index appears in the combination.

```
def restricted_sum(n, s, restrictions):
    """
    Restricted sum problem. Find each list that sums up to a certain number, and obeys restrictions regarding its size and contents.

    input:
    n --            an integer. Indicates the length of the result.
    s --            an integer. Indicates the sum of the result.
    restrictions -- a list of tuples. Indicates the minimum and maximum of each corresponding element in the result. 

    yields:
    result -- A list of positive integers, satisfying the requirements:
        len(result) == n
        sum(result) == s
        for i in range(len(result)):
            restrictions[i][0] <= result[i] <= restrictions[i][1]
    """
    if n == 0:
        if s == 0:
            yield ()
            return
        else:
            return
    else:
        if sum(t[0] for t in restrictions) > s: return
        if sum(t[1] for t in restrictions) < s: return
        l,r = restrictions[0]
        for amt in range(l, r+1):
            for rest in restricted_sum(n-1, s-amt, restrictions[1:]):
                yield (amt,) + rest

def combine(characters, size, character_restrictions):
    assert len(characters) == len(set(characters)) #only works for character sets with no duplicates
    n = len(characters)
    s = size
    restrictions = tuple(character_restrictions[c] for c in characters)
    for seq in restricted_sum(n, s, restrictions):
        yield "".join(c*i for i,c in zip(seq, characters))

symbols = "LNhkPepm3684th"
character_restrictions = {}

#most symbols can appear 0-2 times
for c in symbols:
    character_restrictions[c] = (0,2)

#these characters must appear an exact number of times
limits = {"L":5, "N": 4}
for c, amt in limits.items():
    character_restrictions[c] = (amt, amt)

for result in combine(symbols, 17, character_restrictions):
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
LLLLLNNNN8844tthh
LLLLLNNNN6844tthh
LLLLLNNNN6884tthh
LLLLLNNNN68844thh
LLLLLNNNN68844tth
... 23,462 more values go here...
LLLLLNNNNhh3684hh
... 4,847 more values go here...
LLLLLNNNNhhkkPPe6
LLLLLNNNNhhkkPPe3
LLLLLNNNNhhkkPPem
LLLLLNNNNhhkkPPep
LLLLLNNNNhhkkPPee
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. This is much faster than my previous code but is it possible that I have in results LNL68NLttN8Lh4NLh I need all combination from symbols but with some limits

Comment: For all symols <2 not always 2. And for `limits = {"L":5, "N": 4}` they don't be always together like LLLLL or NNNN. I need that they would be mixed. Not more than 3 times in row. Thank you again Kevin

Comment: "For all symols <2 not always 2": Yes, my answer already does that. For example, "LLLLLNNNNhhkkPPe3" has the character "e" once, and the character "m" zero times. "I need that they would be mixed": then what you are asking for is not "combinations", because a combination always has the same relative order of characters as its input. L is the first symbol in your collection, so it will always appear first in the output.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a kind of "cartesian product with limits"... I think this is possible, but it will require a completely different approach. I'll edit it in if I come up with something.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin for idea. Can you help me how to exclude from my results LLLLLLLLLL and similar. I want to have for all symols <2 not always 2. And for limits = {"L":5, "N": 4} they don't be always together like LLLLL or NNNN. I need that they would be mixed. Not more than 3 times in row.
`import itertools
somelists = [
['L','N','k','P','e','p','m','3','6','8','4','t'],
..... 10 times in total....comment limit
['L','N','k','P','e','p','m','3','6','8','4','t']
          ]
for element in itertools.product(*somelists):
       print(''.join(element))`

Answer (score 1):

Add a dictionary that specifies the limit for each character, and uses that instead of `3` in your condition. You can use `.get()` with a default value so you don't have to specify all the limits.

```
limits = {'Q': 4, 'A': 2}

def combine(arr, s):
    return [x for x in combinations_with_replacement(symbols, s) if max(collections.Counter(x).values()) <= limits.get(x, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar but limits = {'Q': 4, 'A': 2} don't work. Do you have some idea why?

Comment: You accepted the answer, does that mean you got it working?

Comment: No, I made mistake. Still without solution